# How to center text vertically in an EDIT control in pure win32?

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible to center text vertically in an edit control in pure win32 api ? The controls are already super-classed so a sub/super classing solution is not a problem. But shifting/changing to some custom control is not an option.

I am working in c++;

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to do so manually by inserting the appropriate number of spaces.

"RichEdit" is the appropriate Win32 control if you want to center text.

Comment: could you please shed more light on it ?

Comment: Notepad is essentially a decorated EDIT control; Wordpad is a decorated RichEdit control. Compare the two.

Comment: I meant, how ? I looked into RichEdit and seems like it doesn't support Vertical Centering.

Comment: I think it's done via `PARAFORMAT2`, members `dySpaceBefore` and `dySpaceAfter` (when equal, the text would be centered in the Y direction = vertical)

Answer (score -2):

You can apply the `ES_CENTER` window style to an EDIT control.  If it has the `ES_MULTILINE` window style, all of its lines will be centered.

Comment: ES_CENTER centers horizontally.